# JavaScript - fromCharCode is not a function?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, decimal, converters

I'm trying to convert decimal to text like this:

```
function decimalToText(str){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i ++) {
      var text = str.fromCharCode(i);
      arr.push(text);
    }
    return arr.join('');
}
```

So I'd like '104 101 108 108 111 32 119 111 114 108 100' to convert to 'hello world', for example

But I keep getting an `Uncaught TypeError: str.fromCharCode is not a function`

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is String.fromCharCode(number).check this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp

Comment: because it's not a function, it's not prototyped to all strings, it exists on the string constructor

Comment: What are you expecting to pass into this function, and what are you expecting to come out? Please give an example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f9uku64w/

Comment: @DominicTobias I've edited my question with an example of what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Debabrata I understand but how can I implement this into my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. If you take a look at the documentation for [fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) you will first see you are calling it incorrectly

> Because fromCharCode() is a static method of String, you always use it as String.fromCharCode(), rather than as a method of a String object you created.

You can pass in an array of unicode characters and loop through them, for example:

```
function decimalToText(unicodeArray){
    var arr = [];
    for (var index in unicodeArray) {
      var text = String.fromCharCode(unicodeArray[index]);
      arr.push(text);
    }
    return arr.join('');
}

console.log(decimalToText([104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]));
```

Or even cleaner (no loop), you could use the [apply function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
function decimalToText(unicodeArray){
   return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, unicodeArray);
}

console.log(decimalToText([104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]));
```

Or with ES6 you can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
function decimalToText(unicodeArray){
   return String.fromCharCode(...unicodeArray);
}

console.log(decimalToText([104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]));
```

Comment: For me, with Firefox 62.0.3, even the code "var txt=String.fromCharCode(65,65,65,65);" results in error message "TypeError: String.fromCharCode is not a function".